# Search function jQuery don't show the whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I try to build a search function that goes through my `<div>` all `<p>` tags. I manage to make this work but not to 100%. The problem is that the whole `<div>` isn't showed in the end. Only the element that matches the search result is showing. And the video is always showing no matter if there's a match or not in the `<p>` tag.

So, I want everything inside the `<thumbnail>` to be show not only the `<p>` that matches the search. How?

My code:

```js
$('#searchField').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.video-list p').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- form -->

<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="searchField">
  </div>
</form>

<!-- what i'm searching through ( its repeating )-->

<div class="row upload-video video-list">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <div class="video-part">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-w8As0gln6o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <p class="">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>
      <p class="">Horse Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your html will remain same? You want to hide video as well if it not matches your search text?

Comment: You need it like this [http://jsbin.com/yikiwi/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/yikiwi/edit?html,js,output) ??

Comment: @GarvitMangal that's 2 comments with code i've seen in 2 hours - do you not know how to post an answer?

Comment: Exactly @maverickosama92 But I also want the whole div to be shown if the search matches something

Comment: @GarvitMangal No, I want the thumbnail div to not be shown if the search result doesnt match, and if it match I want the entire thumbnail div to be shown, with all its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
 $('#searchField').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  var p_ele = $(".video-list .thumbnail");
  p_ele.each(function(){
    var present = $(this).children("p").text().toLowerCase();
  if(present.indexOf(valThis) == -1){
    $(this).hide();
  }else{
    $(this).show();
  }
  });
});
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/rasuho/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS:

```
var filterFunc = function($parent, valThis){
  var $p = $parent.find("p");
  var found = $p.filter(function(el){          
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(valThis) > -1;
  });

  //hides parent div if we have not found in any of 'p'
  if(found && found.length == 0){
    $parent.hide();
  }else{
    $parent.show();
  }
}

$('#searchField').keyup(function(){
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.video-list').each(function(){
    filterFunc($(this), valThis);
  });
});
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/16956/

Comment: When writing for example "horse", then only that p-tag is showing and both of them

Comment: @teninchhero: you want only p-tag shown in that case?

Comment: No, I want all the content in thumbnail div to be shown

Comment: @teninchhero: "Horse" string only matches in one p-tag not in other tag so why would it be shown if it doesnt contain text inside?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear in my description. The thumbnail div is more than one in the code, I just added one to show as example. Every thumbnail contains information about the same video and you're able to search by video name (first p) and horse name (second p) That's why I want everything in the thumbnail to be shown

Comment: @teninchhero: to be clear, if what you type found in any of the 'p' tag all content should be shown?

Comment: Exactly! Everything in that specific thumbnail div

Comment: Works, thanks! I also fixed it with adding $(this.parentNode).show(); don't know whats best practice?

Comment: Okay, I found a problem. When a result match in one of the above p-tag (lorem ipsum part) it show all the videos..

Comment: @teninchhero: add a fiddle in which there are more than one videos listing.. i can debug that. Post fiddle link here

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is only to display `div.thumbnail` item(s) if search term appears in any of the `div.thumbnail P`. (*since your given html is limited, I assumed that the repeated parent wrapper tag would be `div.thumbnail`* )
But you call your `show/hide function` individually on each `P` tags, which makes the function trigger regardless of it's `siblings` results ( ex: Even if the search-term appears in `div.thumbnail p:nth-of-type[1]`, this will still trigger hide() since it's not found in `div.thumbnail p:nth-of-type[2]` )
So you should attach the `show/hide function` to both child-tags text-results as a whole. See below

```
$('#searchField').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.thumbnail')
    .hide()                     // reset display val of .thumbnail
    .filter(function(){         // get items with search-text only 
        var pTxt = $('p',this).text().toLowerCase();
        return ( pTxt.indexOf(valThis) != -1 ) ?  this : '' ;    
    })
    .show('fast');              // show items with search-text
});
```

[see demo](http://codepen.io/CreativeCreate/pen/ZWNRbN)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).hide()` will hide current element means here `p` so use `$(this).parent().hide()`

```
$('#searchField').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.video-list p').each(function()
    {
       var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
       (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).parent().show() : $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```